# Convert GMT time to specific String Format

Tags: java, date, datetime, gmt

I have specific case that I must take the date field, convert it to GMT time and then to convert it to specific String format.

This gives the GMT time:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Date rightNow = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    TimeZone gmtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
    gmtFormat.setTimeZone(gmtTime);
    System.out.println("GMT Time: " + gmtFormat.format(rightNow));
    String gmtDate=gmtFormat.format(rightNow);
}
```

Now I need to that GMT time convert to String format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`
Example current time in my time zone is `17:10:00`, in GMT `15:10:00` so it means final output should be `2017-08-07T15:10:00Z`

I tried this code to add:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String date = simpleDateFormat.format(gmtDate);
System.out.println(date);
```

But of course I am getting the exception because string cannot be converted like this, but I need something similar.

Comment: Do you *have* to use the old date/time API? The java.time package is much, much nicer. Beyond that, it's not clear what exception you're getting or where...

Comment: Hi I am getting exception at this line:   SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern); this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(Unknown Source)
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(Unknown Source)

Comment: Right, so have you investigated that? Basically your pattern is broken - you need to quote the `T` and the `Z`.

Comment: The correct pattern as shown with complete working examples in the duplicate is `public static final String ISO_8601_24H_FULL_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX";` As per [ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations). Do **not** hard code the `Z` at the end as is suggested by others.

Answer (score -1):

Merge your 2 codeblocks together:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
  Date rightNow = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
  String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
  DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
  TimeZone gmtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
  gmtFormat.setTimeZone(gmtTime);
  System.out.println("GMT Time: " + gmtFormat.format(rightNow));
}
```

Or `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"` as per [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)...

Comment: this is not working: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(Unknown Source)
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(Unknown Source)
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at ibis.test.EricssonDate.main(EricssonDate.java:34)

Comment: This is exactly the same exception which I am getting with my code also

Comment: To be honest, i just copied your original pattern, did not looked it to be working. Corrected by @RobinTopper...

Comment: no their edit was incorrect as well